# How to use custom underline with breakline in CSS?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, dotted-line

I would like to stylize my link with a background.

When the link is short I have no problem with my background, but my link is too long, I have a break line and my background doesn't work anymore. I don't want use `text-decoration: underline` because it's not the same design (custom dotted with spaces between them)

HTML :

```
<a href="#">Ceci est un menu très long</a>
<a href="#">Blabl</a>
```

CSS :

```
a {  
   background: url(dotted.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

Here is my problem :

[image]

Is it possible do that, like below ?

[image]

and :

[image]

Comment: Can you show the CSS you are using so we can help amend for you?

Comment: Set your element to display:inline. to break line in between them, you will need a <br/> or any other tag displayed as block level element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'><span>click here to do something</span></a>
```

Comment: Yep, this will do it... and you type faster than me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a hudge margin right, even if that sounds strange :)  : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z545p/)**

```
a {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-right:100%;
}
```

[image: inline, but breaks line]

Comment: I am suspicious that this would have negative consequences

Comment: @AlexW what kind ? , it might just do nothing at all

Comment: @AlexW couple of test : http://jsfiddle.net/z545p/2/ do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

**HTML  :**

```
<a href='#'><span>click here to do something</span></a>
```

**CSS :**

```
a{
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:100px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
span{
 border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dGw2c/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in modern browsers with the `border-image` property: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/Gdxpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

div {
    width: 120px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;  
    line-height: 1.6em; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-width: 0 0 9px 0;
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-24554400/border.png) 9 repeat; /* Safari */
    -o-border-image: url(http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-24554400/border.png) 9 repeat;; /* Opera */
    border-image: url(http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-24554400/border.png) 9 repeat;;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><a href="">Some text with an underline and background</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks good, but the dotted is not the same... that's why I use a custom background

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of `border-image`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want personnalised design you have [border-image also](http://caniuse.com/border-image) but Ie11...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add images for dotted underlines. You can simply use css's border-bottom property for the same.

```
<a href="#">Ceci est un menu très bla bla bla bla nla bla bla bla nla</a> 

a{
  border-bottom : 2px dotted #CCC;
  text-decoration : none;  
 }
```

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/mijoemathew/zhp6D/ for testing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the span and make the a{display:inline}.

```
<a href='#'>click here to do something</a>

a {
 display:inline;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Matze/2frgctk7/)

Cleaner and works like a charm.